# Two collection views in a viewcontroller, collectionview A scrolls while collectionview B does not

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode6, xcode8

So here's the code.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.recommendedGamesCollectionView {
        return 1
    } else if collectionView == self.topGamesCollectionView {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.recommendedGamesCollectionView {
        return 6
    } else if collectionView == self.topGamesCollectionView {
        return 6
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == self.recommendedGamesCollectionView {
        let cell:RecommendedCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecommendedCell", for: indexPath) as? RecommendedCell)!
        return cell
    } else if collectionView == self.topGamesCollectionView {
        let cell:TopGamesCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TopGamesCell", for: indexPath) as? TopGamesCell)!
        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

The funky monkey collectionview is the only one that is scrolling. The collection view at the bottom does not. Scrolling for both collectionviews were also enabled in Attributes Inspector. They were also set to scroll and bounce horizontally.

[image]

Comment: How do you set frame for these collectionviews? Using autolayout?

Comment: I embedded the collectionviews in a View which is also embedded in a Scroll View. Yes I was using autolayout constraints.

Scroll View works fine, CollectionView A Scrolling works fine, but CollectionView B does not scroll.

Comment: Did you use Debug View Hierarchy? Is there any other view over lapping in top of the second collection view?

Comment: There's no other overlapping view.